# Visual Studio 2010 Compiler Options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, compiler-options

I can't find the option people call "C/C++" on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate's Project Property Pages to change some compiler options. Here's what i got:

[image: Screenshot of property pages]

I've tried creating an Empty Project and a Win32 Project set to empty with no result. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check @Joel's answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't show the C/C++ properties until you have at least one .cpp file in your project (might also accept other file types, but .h does not work).

So add a single .cpp file to your project and when you go to the property pages, it should show up right above the Linker settings.

Comment: Thanks, i knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 1):

in the additional options, add `/TP` for C++ and `/TC` for C.

`/TP` will compile all the files as C++, regardless of their file extensions. `/TC` will compile all the files as C, regardless of their file extensions.